# Which Linux LiveCD is best in general use for fixing windows boxes?

Tags: windows, linux, repair, linux-distributions

**Story**: 
At our University, the tech help desk is decidedly low-tech. Virus outbreaks are frequent and users, of course, haven't backed up. Recently I pulled out a Linux LiveCD (Mint 8 for the curious) in order to manually remove some virus executables. The other people working the desk were impressed. However I was just using a general purpose LiveCD. Since this comes up frequently, I've been thinking about having a general-issue LiveCD for any of our not-so-technically-inclined consultants to use.

**Question**:
For our *not-so-technically-inclined* help-desk workers, which relatively easy-to-use "Repair and Rescue" free-to-use Live CD would in your humble opinion work best for this problem?

We're looking specifically for:

- File Recovery
- Virus Detection/Removal
- Registry Repair

and of course

- relatively user friendly (GUI?)

Comment: Perhaps leave out the Linux and make it LiveCD or portable OS? Since we're going to get some discussion on the UBCD answers I reckon...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't use a Linux live cd, I would use the [Ultimate Boot CD For Windows](http://www.ubcd4win.com/), It has pretty much everything needed to fix up a Windows machine, and a whole lot more.

Also, if your campus has software assurance, you may be able to get the [Microsoft Desktop Optimisation Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/enterprise/products/mdop/default.aspx) which includes [DART](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/enterprise/products/mdop/dart.aspx) (Microsoft Diagnostics and Recovery Toolset), a brilliant fixing tool.

Answer (score 4):

The **[Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/)** has got it all ...

Comment: Oh I'm so looking forward to your edits ;-P

Answer (score 0):

Linux is hands down better at fixing Windows than Windows. Linux ignores the "special files" so you can, for example, file copy from one hard disk to another and boot off that hard disk.

The best distro is [Ubuntu Rescue Remix](http://www.ubuntu-rescue-remix.org/), however it doesn't have GUI. If you want a GUI then [download a standard Ubuntu image](http://www.ubuntu.com/), burn it to disk and run that. It has most of the tools you'll need but some you'll need to install (easy as pie) as required.

Comment: I didn't get the «special files ignore» — what is it? Perhaps did you mean that GNU/Linux allows creation filenames that are disallowed in Windows?